# Create TextBox inside the canvas of Html5

Tags: html

I am trying to place a `TextBox` inside html5. Is it possible to place a `TextBox` inside the `Canvas`? If it is, then please help me do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple.

You have to put your textbox inside a div and then change the div position.
In order to do this, under your body tag:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div id="mytext"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> .....
```

Under your head tag:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    #mytext {
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    top: 725px;
    z-index: 999;
    }

</style>
```

By changing the left and top value you can place the textbox on your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is used to put graphics elements, like drawings, shapes etc. You cannot put a form element on a canvas. You will need to include a `div` or something alike to do that.

Comment: could you give me any example to do so @MotaBOS